# Need Cygwin expect script to output files based on Date to specified folders

Tags: bash, date, for-loop, cygwin, expect

I have just written a script to automate the backup of our Cisco devices to a specified folder. /home/myusername/Backups

What I would like to accomplish is to have the script run once a week, dump the outputs into the Backups folder, but instead of overwriting them, storing the old configs in a separate directory. We would like to keep 1 month worth of backups if possible. When the script runs and a new output is written, the previous copy would move down the file tree. File Tree would look as such:

```
/Backups(newest backup)
--1_Week_Old
--2_Weeks_Old 
--3_Weeks_Old
--4_Weeks_Old
```

Here is an example of the existing script I have written. It works well, but I know it could be shortened with some gained experience. I am new to scripting so go easy....

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

# These are all the IP's:
set ip1 "X.X.X.X"

#These are all the hostnames:
set hostname1 "ASA_Firewall"

#These are the usernames
set username   "RickyBobby"

# These are all the passwords:
set password         "xxxxxxx"
set enableasa        "xxxxxxxxx"

#This is the ASA Firewall - Point TFTP Directory to C:\cygwin\home\RickyBobby\Backups
spawn ssh $ip1
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"

  expect ">" {
    send "en\n"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$enableasa\r"
  }
expect "#"
send "copy run tftp://X.X.X.X/Backups/$hostname1-confg\r"
expect "Source filename?"
send "\r"
expect "Address or name of remote host?"
send "X.X.X.X\r"
expect "Destination filename?"
send "\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
```

I am still in the process of learning so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: good question: pretty clear description of the problem and a demonstration of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a sequence of directory rename commands. Assuming you're OK with deleting whatever is in the "week 4" directory:

```
cd /home/username/Backups
file delete -force ./4_Weeks_Old
file rename 3_Weeks_Old 4_Weeks_Old
file rename 2_Weeks_Old 3_Weeks_Old
file rename 1_Week_Old  2_Weeks_Old 

# move files in Backups to 1 week dir
file mkdir 1_Week_Old
file rename -- {*}[glob -types f -- *] 1_Week_Old
```

If your version of expect has Tcl older than version 8.5, you'll have to move the files with

```
for file [glob -types f -- *] {
    file rename $f 1_Week_Old/$f
}
```

or the ugly

```
set cmd [linsert [glob -types f -- *] 0 file rename --]
eval [lappend cmd 1_Week_Old]
```

I use `--` in case there happens to be a filename beginning with a dash, so that filename will be treated as a filename and not an option.

Your expect script looks good. One tip: while developing an expect script, either run it with "expect -d" or add this line near the beginning: `exp_internal 1` -- that turns on verbose debugging output so you can see how your patterns are matching.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Glenn. I'm in the process of trying some of the above commands. I am fine with deleting what comes out of "week 4", in fact that's what I wanted. I went ahead and added exp_internal 1 to it as well. I will let you know what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: Question also Glenn, sorry for the newbie questions, but should this be appended to the end of my expect script?

Comment: yes. Also, add `expect eof` after you send "exit". That will wait for the ssh process to end.